# Удерживание клавиши для ввода

Tags: c++, ввод

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: пользователю требуется нажать и удерживать пробел, и до тех пор, пока он его не отпустит, в консоль должен выводиться символ. Не знаю как заставить `getch` реагировать на удерживание клавиши.

```
void PressKey()
{
    int key = getch();

    if (key == ' ')
    {
        cout << "#";
    }
}
```

Comment: В цикле считывать? :) Или использовать API операционной системы...

Comment: Я думал насчет цикла, но while (key == ' ') зацикливает программу.

Comment: `for(int key=getch(); key==' '; key=getch()) { cout << '#'; }` но это фигня - потому что отработает **не на отпускание клавиши**, а на ввод чего-то другого. Если просто отпустить - остановится и будет ждать нажатия другой клавиши.

Answer (score 1):

```
void PressKey()
{
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x20))
    {
        cout << "#";
    }
}
```

Эта функция соответственно должна быть в цикле

Comment: Можете пожалуйста написать условия для цикла? У меня не получается сделать так, чтобы реагировало на отпускание клавиши.

Comment: @rollwithit - да самое обычное void PressKey()
{
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x20))
    {
        cout << "#";
    }
}                                                                                                             int main(){while(true){PressKey();}return 0;}